# VideoCapture not working on Android with C++

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have a video file saved on my Android device.

Using a `getPath()` function I got "sdcard/video_app/sample_video.avi".

I'm now trying to use this video file in my OpenCV C++ code (I'm using NDK and JNI) with this :

```
VideoCapture capture("sdcard/video_app/sample_video.avi");

if(capture.isOpened()){
    //return true
   }else{
    //return false
    }
```

I added :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

It always returns false. What am I doing wrong ? I read that OpenCV on android only supports MJPEG codec in avi container so I'm using this kind of video file and it's still not working.

EDIT :

I've changed the path :

```
VideoCapture capture("/storage/emulated/0/turning_pages.avi");
```

This path is the response from a call to `Environment.getExternalDirectory.getPath()` 
The path is correct, I've verified it with this :

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/turning_pages.avi");
if(file.exists()){
     //returns true
  }
```

I've done some more testing and imread and imwrite are wroking fine using similar path, I can conclude that the problem with VideoCapture is not from the path.

```
Mat m = imread("/storage/emulated/0/sbuinex21fyy.jpg"); 

if(!m.empty()){
   //returns true
   } 

imwrite("/storage/emulated/0/sbuinex21fyy.jpg", m);
```

I can then see a duplicate of the picture in my device storage.

Comment: That looks like a relative path. Is that really correct? i.e. does the current working directory of your apllication contain a subdirectory `sdcard`, which contains...

Comment: I've changed the path since the question, the path now used is "/storage/emulated/0/turning_pages.avi", which is the response from Environment.getExternalStorage.getPath(); and it still doesn't work. (The path is working in Android java code for creating a new file for example (File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/turning_pages.avi") )

Comment: OK, can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44058968/edit) the question so it's up to date? TBH, i don't have any Android experience, but the relative path seemed to indicate a fairly common issue. Your latest comment didn't make it clear (although you seem to have edited it since) what was the result of the change you mention. Please make it clear in the question that this is not a case of having an invalid path ;)

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify.